# Android Studio - Widget above soft keyboard in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Is it possible in `RelativeLayout` using `android:layout_above` to place a widget above the soft keyboard when it's visible? 
**I don't want to fiddle with any layouts**, as the ones I have in my project should remain unaffected by the widget I'm trying to add.

Answer (score 1):

The soft keyboard exists in a separate process and gets its own separate window. There's no way for you to reference the soft keyboard in your layouts or position anything in relation to it directly.

In your AndroidManifest, you can specify `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`. This means your activity's window will be resized when the soft kayboard window is visible. In this scenario, any view positioned at the bottom of your activity's layout should appear directly above the soft keyboard. This is the best you can do.

Comment: Hmm, thought that was the case. I can't really use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` since i use `android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout`  for some of my layouts, and adjusting the screen size will mess up their proportions, but thanks for the answer nonetheless!